# React Native - Hide keyboard on scroll

Tags: javascript, react-native, keyboard, scrollview

I am using [Keyboard Aware ScrollView](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view) to wrap my content and avoid keyboard overflowing focused `TextInput`.

However, I wish to hide the keyboard if the user decides to scroll through the content. Currently, if that is the situation, the user can scroll through the contents freely, but the keyboard will not hide. Is this possible to achieve using this library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view documentation this component accepts ScrollView, SectionList and FlatList default props, so try using keyboardDismissMode prop and set it to 'on-drag'

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have the same problem on a normal FlatList, i tried the prop you suggested, works fine on iOS but no changes on Android. Any suggestion?

Comment: Hey @vitosorriso according to the documentation keyboardDismissMode 'on-drag' is for both platforms so check if you have something preventing it from working on android